# Center a flex item when its siblings have different widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I know flexbox offers a great solution for centering items. But I run into an issue when I have 3 items and I'd like the center (2nd) item to be centered with respect to the window, regardless of the size of the other 2 items.

In my pen you can see the second item "Client Index" is off-center because the content on the right is larger than the content on the left.  **How can I force it to center itself?**

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span style="font-size:12px;">small</span>
  <span style="font-size:20px;">Client Index</span>
  <span style="font-size:18px;">Lots of content that moves the center</span>
</div>
```

[My Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pjqjvd)

Answer (score 12):

One way would be to set `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0` so the 3 columns are distributed evenly, then you can center the text or the content in the middle one.

I'm using `text-align` to center the middle column. You could also use `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to do the same thing.

```css
.flex { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex > span {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.flex > span:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span style="font-size:12px;">small</span>
  <span style="font-size:20px;">Client Index</span>
  <span style="font-size:18px;">Lots of content that moves the center</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use nested flex containers and `auto` margins.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item:first-child>span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex-item:last-child>span {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* non-essential */
.flex-item {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"><span>short</span></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><span>medium</span></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><span>lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's how it works:

- The top-level div is a flex container.
- Each child div is now a flex item.
- Each item is given `flex: 1` in order to distribute container space equally.
- Now the items are consuming all space in the row and are equal width.
- Make each item a (nested) flex container and add `justify-content: center`.
- Now each `span` element is a centered flex item.
- Use flex `auto` margins to shift the outer `span`s left and right.

You could also forgo `justify-content` and use `auto` margins exclusively.

But `justify-content` can work here because `auto` margins always have priority. From the spec:

> [**8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.